# Adiabatic Availability?

Tags: thermodynamics, terminology, adiabatic

In the textbook 
"Thermodynamics: Foundations and Applications" by Elias P. Gyftopoulas and Gian Paolo Beretta (Dover).

In chapter 5, on page 73 (section 5.3) the book says: 
**Adiabatic availability** is *the largest amount of energy that can be transferred to a weight in a weight process without net changes in the values of amounts of constituents and parameters* .

For my astonishment from my limited understanding of Thermodynamics, the above statement contradicts the classic way a process is defined and would someway be a PMM1.

Is there a better way of understanding this concept. Have perused through https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/adiabatic-availability-and-changing-states.631135/ and haven't found a satisfactory answer..

Do point me in the right direction.
A picture representing this (from Google Books)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

So let's start first off with a category error. The statement you are reading is a **definition** and therefore cannot have any physical content -- you cannot create a perpetual motion device out of some definitions; you would have to create it out of some sort of strange physics phenomenon.

Then let me try to understand you better as perhaps saying "if this definition is to be useful the number it defines must not be constant, but if this number was not the constant 0 then wouldn't that imply a perpetual motion device?"

So I think the key here is that this textbook is very careful to define "amounts of constituents" as literally a number of particles under investigation and "parameters" as literally the parameters defining the environment of the system, but that this is not comprehensive and in fact there are a number of internal degrees of freedom that the system is supposed to have. Those internal degrees of freedom are certainly allowed to change. For example my system might consist of another weight with variable height; we might transfer energy into or out of that system by changing the height of the weight. Similarly we might have a fixed box containing a bunch of liquid water, but we might transfer energy into it by evaporating that water into steam or transfer energy out by condensing the steam into liquid water. Similarly we might have a solid box containing inside a battery and an electric motor, and that could be a system. The battery's charge is not a "parameter" as they are defining it -- an external parameter imposed by the environment. Instead it refers to something stored within the system in the "internal forces" of that system.

The claim is that if you connect those systems to some pulley which can raise a weight or lower it, there is some set of processes which raises that weight to a maximal height. The processes which do so are going to contain a significant subset -- those are the reversible processes from the initial state to a stable equilibrium state for the system. (There might be other irreversible processes or reversible processes to a state that's not in equilibrium that also extract that amount of energy, but that subset is nevertheless significant for the analysis.)

The reversibility matters because any other process to any other state can be regarded (by composing with the reversed process) as a process from the stable equilibrium to that other state extracting some sum of the two amounts of work. If this total energy were greater than zero, the other state would have lower energy and the equilibrium would not actually be stable. So it's part of the definition of "stable" equilibrium that this energy must be maximal, if the reversible process ending on such a state exists in the first place. (One way of viewing the second law of thermodynamics is just asserting that this process and the equilibrium it points to *does* exist for every state, so that we are not merely talking about nothing here -- I am a little fuzzy on whether the proof guarantees that the process which exists to connect you to some stable equilibrium must be reversible.)